# Scale parentLayout without scaling its childView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am scaling and translating my parent layout, but the problem is my child view is also scaling and but not translating according to its parent(I want my child view to be at the center of the screen, no matter where my parent layout is translating).

Below is my code

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

Animation zoomIn,zoomOut;
ImageView icon;
LinearLayout relativeLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    zoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.zoom_in);
    zoomOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.zoom_out);

    relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.utt);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    relativeLayout.setAnimation(zoomIn);
    relativeLayout.setAnimation(zoomOut);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   layoutParams.height= 75;
    layoutParams.width = 75;
    layoutParams.gravity= Gravity.CENTER;
    icon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);



    zoomIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {




        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

          relativeLayout.startAnimation(zoomOut);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    zoomOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            icon.setAlpha(1.0f);

            icon.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.translate_top_center));


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

          relativeLayout.startAnimation(zoomIn);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

}
```

**It's Activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="store.shopnix.com.kenburns.Splash">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
```

**anim.xml**

zoom_in

```
 <scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="20000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:repeatMode = "reverse"
    android:translationX="100dp"
    android:translationY = "100dp">
</scale>
```

zoom_out

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="20000"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="70%"
    android:pivotY="20%"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode = "reverse"
    android:translationX="20dp"
    android:translationY = "20dp">
</scale>
```

Comment: Can't you put things that you don't want to be animated in a separate layout? For that your root layout should allow overlapping (for example `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`)

Comment: by doing this can this problem be solved

Comment: Of course, you scale one `layout` and the other one stays still.

Comment: I am scaling Linear Layout, and if i put <include/> view will it work

Comment: I will write a full answer for ya. Wait a couple of minutes please.

Comment: If the childView is not translating properly inside the parentView, then you should play around with pivotX and pivotY of the scale animation, that should help fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create two separate layouts, one that scales and other that doesn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_to_scale">
        <!--put stuff that scales here-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_to_stay">
        <!--put static stuff here-->
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now in your `activity` animate only layout with `id` = `R.id.layout_to_scale`

Comment: Thanks a ton , but i want to scale parent background image, without changing its child views..

Comment: Just add `ImageView` into `layout_to_scale` and set its `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. When you're comfortable, you may refactor code a bit and replace `layout_to_scale` with your `ImageView`

Comment: this one worked, but as the background is zooming in the image view is also zooming in, can't we have a relative scaling so that the image view is scaled opposite with respect to the background

Comment: Hmm, decide what you want please, first you said that you want you image to scale, now you don't. If you don't want some view to scale put it into `layout_to_stay`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of **LinearLayout** you can use **RelativeLayout** and place the childView inside it .

now you add property **android:layout_centerInParent="true"** for childView 
now you can scale the **RelativeLayout** without scaling the childView it will definitely stay in centre of parentView(**RelativeLayout**).

Hope this solves your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="store.shopnix.com.kenburns.Splash">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:alpha="0.0"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```